# Does free() free memory at all depths or only at the highest level?

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, free

Suppose I have a struct defined this way:

```
struct myStruct{
    data* anotherStruct;
}
```

Suppose I allocate memory on the heap for a struct of type `myStruct`. The pointer to this struct is called `ptr`. I then call `free(ptr)`. Does this free the memory allocated just for myStruct, or does it free the memory allocated for `myStruct` and `anotherStruct`?

If it frees only the memory allocated for `myStruct`, does this lead to a memory leak because there is no pointer to `anotherStruct` and that can never be freed?

Answer (score 3):

It frees only the memory allocated to that address. i.e: Yes the highest level.

> **Does this free the memory allocated just for myStruct, or does it free the memory allocated for `myStruct` and `anotherStruct`?**

It only frees memory allocated to `myStruct`.

> **If it frees only the memory allocated for `myStruct`, does this lead to a memory leak because there is no pointer to `anotherStruct` and that can never be freed?**

If you don't have a pointer to `anotherStruct` then yes it leakes the memory. The usual strategy is to deallocate memory in reverse order of the order you allocated it.

For ex: In your case you first allocated `myStruct` and then `anotherStruct`, So you should deallocate in exactly inverse order, i.e: free `anotherStruct` first and then  `myStruct`.

Answer (score 1):

Only the highest level. It's not quite that smart.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thanks for your answer. More context would help.

Answer (score 1):

In the code

```
struct myStruct *ptr = malloc(sizeof(myStruct));
.
.
.
free(ptr);
```

nothing shown has affected the `anotherStruct` member of `*ptr`, `ptr->anotherStruct`.  You'd probably want to use `malloc` to point `ptr->anotherStruct` to a useful block of memory.  You'd then have to call `free(ptr->anotherStruct)` *before* calling `free(ptr)` to avoid any memory leaks.

It can be quite useful to define initialization and destruction functions in order to handle such "internal (de)allocation" automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Address is the key for freeing memory. each `malloc()` returned memory is a separate key. so upper block(i.e memory allocated for myStruct type) only freed and leads to memory leak.

Best practice is to free those internal blocks, then free the upper one. otherwise you will loose the pointer address if not stored anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

"free" can only free the memory allocated at the highest level. The simple reason being, for the pointer members inside a struct, you may or may not allocate memory from the heap. How will free be able to keep track from where all pointer member's memory came from?

Answer (score 0):

it only frees the the memory allocated to that address, if you would like to free the whole chained list then you will have to loop through it and free one element each time (a struct in your case), you will have to save the address to the next struct free the actual pointer then move to the next one and keep doing till you reach the pointer that points to null.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as everyone said , it will free the memory allocated only for the struct, NOT what the anotherStruct points to. it will certainly make memory leak. it is programmers responsibility to free the memory allocated dynamically.

you can use a tool "valgrind" to check the memory leak.